# Have to move mouse out of viewport and back in for javascript to take effect

Tags: javascript, css

Javascript mouseover and mouseout events don't seem to be working when I first load the page. Strangely, if I move the mouse out of the viewport up to the top of the screen for a second or two and come back into the viewport, the javascript kicks in and works as expected.

Here is the html css and javascript:

```js
const picWindows =  document.querySelectorAll(".window");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");


  picWindows.forEach((item) => {
   item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
   item.classList.add("active");
  });
  
   item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    item.classList.remove("active");
  });
  
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container.classList.toggle("active");
    item.classList.toggle("show");
  });
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }



  body {
    background: #27ae60;
    box-shadow: inset 70px 70px 250px #000,
    inset -70px -70px 250px #000;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

.container.active::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
  
  .window {
    height: 100%;
    transition: flex .5s cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.52,1.53);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .window1 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518495973542-4542c06a5843?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .window2 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601758176559-76c75ead317a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .window3 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601758174039-617983b8cdd9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
   flex: 1;
  }
  
  .window4 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587502536263-5dda37cd33f0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 1;
  }

.window5 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1422564030440-1ecae6e21f67?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 1;
  }

.window6 {
    background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553531384-397c80973a0b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60") no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .active {
    flex: 3;
  }

.show {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>Expand Images Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="window window1"></div>
        <div class="window window2"></div>
        <div class="window window3"></div>
        <div class="window window4"></div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help in understanding this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try putting your script tag just before the closing </body> tag and remove the defer argument? You probably should wrap your JS code in a self executing function (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses! For some reason the problem was only happening in Chrome. Strangely enough I had to remove and re-install Chrome and now everything is working as expected. A strange one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking if the page is loaded then assigning the values and listeners would help.

```
window.onload = () => {
  const picWindows = document.querySelectorAll(".window");
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");

  picWindows.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      item.classList.add("active");
    });

    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
      item.classList.remove("active");
    });

    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      container.classList.toggle("active");
      item.classList.toggle("show");
    });
  });
};
```